# Synchronize users created with Firebase Auth to my custom backend

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to use Firebase Auth for my user login/registration process. Everything else should be handled by my own backend (spring boot app + postgres db).

Now I'm asking myself how I can synchronize a new created user to my user table in postgres. I thought about the following:

1. REST call through client - Everytime I get a success event from the firebase sdk I call an additional request to my backend which sends uid, username etc.

Problem: What if my backend call fails but the register process was successful ? That would lead to an inconsistent state since (at least thats what I understanded) I can't easily rollback. That would lead to situations where a user can login into my app without my backend knowing the user. This would crash/ invalidate all my following queries (e.g. search after user xyz would lead to no result even though he/she exists)

2. Check the existence of the user in the postgres database

Here I would query the uid from the database (which I got from the jwt) and create a new user if it doesn't exists in every incoming request.

Problem: The user query is a unnessecary overhead for every incoming request.

3. Trigger with cloud functions - When I understood it right firebase auth is firing events when a new user is created in cloud functions. This could be used to make the external api call.

Problem: I dont know what happens when my external rest call fails at this point. Can I rollback the registration ? Will I be ever catch this event again ? I also proably would have an eventual consistency situation, since I dont know when the cloud function triggers. Furthermore I would prefer not to include cloud functions to my stack

Is there any way how I could do this in a transactional manner ? Did anyone else tried is using sth simular ?

Thanks for every help!

Comment: This is a great question, I am trying to do something similar, such as initialising some user specific data right after login, ideally I hope this operation can be part of the registration flow in firebase...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I finally came up with a different solution:

1. Register user per Firebase SDK (e.g. with email + pw method)
2. Make a post-call to my own registration api including the resulting uid from the previous step and some metadata
3. API creates a new user including a column with the UID + Fetches the firebase token of the user and adds an internal claim that references to the internal Postgres UUID via Admin SDK.
4. Frontend gets the created user and hard refreshes (very important, since the previously fetched token won't contain the newly added claim !) the firebase token and verifies that it contains the token. If it does -> everything is cool, if not some oopsie happened :) That will require a request retry.

Later when you start your app you can just check if the passed token contains the custom claim, if not open the sign up/sign in page.
Every endpoint except the one for registration should check if the claim is set. If not just forbid the request.

How to set custom claims:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk

Comment: Very interesting approach. I 've stumbled upon a similar problem, and I am still trying to figure out the "proper" way to do things. One concern that I have with your approach is that although in your servers/database or event front-end logic, if anything fails on step (2) will mean that the user is not logged in, Firebase SDK will consider the user as logged in since step (1) was a success. And this is persistent across multiple sessions. So  your frontend has to either logout the user after failure of step (2) or neglect the auth state indicated by Firebase SDK. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your right. When step (2) fails, your http request should return some 400/500 response. If you can catch the exception in your backend before returning the error response, then you can also directly delete this user with the admin sdk. But if the response fails without the backend noticing (e.g. server down / maintance etc.) then your frontend can handle a logout and retry the request. It's a bit nasty not gonna lie, but I couldn't find a better way :/

Comment: I understand, indeed it is not an easy "riddle" to solve, but in the project I am working on it is very important to have 1-1 sync between firebase users and database entities. Probably it would be more robust to invest on a solution based on option (3). The reason? it is easier to guarantee success (even with some retries) in the communication between a cloud function and your rest api, than having to orchestrate a sequence of calls that will happen in the user's browser (rough calculation, including calls to firebase = at least 3 http calls for simple auth, and 4 for google login).

Comment: Was this the final solution you ended up using?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is actually to *not* synchronize auth data, but instead [decode and verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) of the user in your backend code.

This operation is (by design) stateless, although Firebase's own backend services often implement a cache of recently decoded tokens to speed up future calls with the same ID token.

Comment: Verfication was clear to me, but I can't proceed without storing user data. I need a user model in my db to link with other entities, do searching etc. I want to be flexible with those data. Your suggestion is not really a solution for me

Comment: So how about storing the information from the ID token in your database when the request comes in then? So on each request: decode the token, store (or update) that information in your database, pass along the request to the proper place.

Comment: So basically option 2. of my original question ? I don't want to do this, since then I have to query my database in every possible api request my backend offers. That sounds a bit inefficient, because a user which uses the app will still trigger this query. Or did you mean sth different ? Thx for the reply

Comment: If you can do an upsert, you won't need to do a separate query.

Comment: Well, a write op sounds even worse :D

Comment: How about using a custom claim for this purpose? If the claim (maybe a boolean flag like isSynced) doesn't exist, it inserts the user to the db and adds the claim via firebase admin sdk. If it is existing, no query or upsert is required. With having in mind that the token has to be refreshed. You see any problems with that option ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Firebase Admin SDK to create the user account from your back-end instead of from the client.
So first you create the user in your database, then grab the ID and use it to create a user with the same ID in Firebase.

If all goes well, send a confirmation to the client and sign it in using the same credentials they entered.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an endpoint in your backend service and call this endpoint when a client side authentication succeeds?

This method should do 2 things:

1. decode token to get access to Firebase user object (Firebase Admin)
2. Compare Firebase user with your internal user table. if it doesn't exist you can create it using firebase user object, otherwise do nothing.

This solution allows you to do other nice things as well (Syncing user info between Firebase and your internal db, providing a way to let a frontend know if this user is new or not, ...) at a relative small cost (1 get call per sign in)

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Firebase Authentication with a custom authentication system by modifying your authentication server to produce custom signed tokens when a user successfully signs in. Your app receives this token and uses it to authenticate with Firebase.

[Read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)